# How can I check the number of days remaining in my Windows XP free trial period?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-activation

I've extended it with a command in Start -> Run twice or three times, already. I got a message saying that I have 7 days remaining, but I can't remember how many days ago that was.

Comment: You should be able to get that message back by doing a simple restart.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an XP system to try this from anymore, but a quick google search says:

Click Start, Run and type in: msinfo32 and Press OK.

Answer (score 1):

Press "Windows + Pause" to pull up system information-- the same dialog as if you right-click "My Computer" and selected "Properties." Windows registration information is presented there, if I recall. It certainly does for Windows 7 on that screen anyway.